# How to attach Product Information to xml serializer dll

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `ProductInfo.cs` file that provides updated fileversion to dlls when running a build.
But a project in my solution generates two dlls

1. general dll
2. xmlSerializer dll

The file version that xmlSerializer has is incorrect and not matching with the fileversion of `ProductInfo.cs`

Is there any way to map it correctly.

Comment: How do you generate XmlSerializers dll? Using `sgen` in post build event? Also what is the `ProductInfo.cs`, does it contain assembly attibutes? Please, share it

Comment: ProductInfo.cs contains assembly attributes.
and yes Sgen is used

Comment: The xml serializer uses classes I suspect are in the general dll.  So you need to recompile the xmlSerializer dll so it matches the general dll classes.  Check the dates of the dlls to make sure all have been updated.

Comment: All are updated but file version is incorrect